# Mainnet program deployment hygiene

Tags: anchor, keypair, deploy, mainnet

Clearly having a single local keypair control mainnet program deployments is a horrible idea. Are there any well defined workflows to increasing security for deployments? Any handy multisig tools built purposefully for this task? I have a hard time reasoning with the notion that most people deploy to mainnet-beta using random keypairs they generate locally yet I am not aware of what the popular alternatives are

Answer (score 1):

The spl gov site supports assigning the program upgrade authority to a DAO governance. This means upgrades happen via DAO votes and the upgrade authority can't be lost.

For example mango DAO has the upgrade authority for a number of their programs https://app.realms.today/dao/MNGO/assets
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use SnowFlake they have this nice feature to manage program authority from the multisig itself. Check it [here](https://safe.snowflake.so/)